# how to upload image and file in webview on android version 4.4 and 7.1.1

Tags: android, webview

1. This code work on **Lollipop(5.0)**,**marshmallow(6.0)**,**Oreo (8.1.1)** but not on Kitkat(4.4) and Nougat(7.1.1).
2. I did debug this code on android version Nougat then i find `ValueCallback<Uri>` refrence object `mUMA` get null in `onActivityResult()` method but this code work properly android version Lollipop,marshmallow,Oreo .

**Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    public Uri imageUri;
    private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;
    private  String mCM = null;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUM = null;
    private  ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR = 1;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (permissions.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    init();
                }
        }
    }

    public void init() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.requestFocus();
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }


        //webView.loadUrl("http://www.linkfolo.com");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/index.html");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            //For Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FCR);
            }

            // For Android 3.0+, above method not supported in some android 3+ versions, in such case we use this
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                        FCR);
            }

            //For Android 4.1+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUM = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("*/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FCR);
            }

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        init();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == FCR) {
                    if (mUMA == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent == null) {
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if (mCM != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    } else {
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, data)
            if (results != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
                mUMA = null;
            }
        } else {
            if (requestCode == FCR) {
                if (null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
    }


    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (webView.canGoBack()) {

            webView.goBack();

        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }


        //Show loader on url load
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            // in standard case YourActivity.this
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
                progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try {
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```